# How Does One Come Up With This Proof of The Triangle Inequality of Complex Integrals?

Tags: problem-solving, complex-integration, triangle-inequality

I saw this proof in the textbook and wonder what might have motivated it?

Set $\theta = \arg \int^b_a f(t) \,dt$ then $$\left|\int^b_a f(t) \,dt\right|=e^{-i\theta}\int^b_a f(t) \,dt = \Re e^{-i\theta}\int^b_a f(t) \,dt=\int^b_a\Re e^{-i\theta}f(t)\,dt \leq\int_a^b|f(t)|\,dt$$

It makes sense but how does one come up with this?

Comment: As with most clever proofs like this, probably someone came up with it after a more complicated proof was found. Maybe long after. Sometimes, “clever” proofs clarify, but others feel like magic tricks which obscure more more than elucidate.

Comment: It’s possible someone found the equivalent proof for finite sums of complex numbers, first, showing:$$\left|\sum x_i\right|\leq \sum \left|x_i\right|$$ The same proof works here.

Comment: Note this theorem holds for $n$ dimensional integrals in general: $$\left\lVert \int_{S}f(x)\,dx\right\rVert \leq \int_{S}\lVert f(x)\rVert\,dx$$